# How to send the event to the lambda_handler function from the command line using Zappa

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zappa

I'm using Zappa and I want to send the event to my lambda_handler function using the `invoke` command. I'm using the `--raw` flag, which means I'm sending python code.

I'm using Zappa 0.38.0, Python 2.7.10 and I've checked the official repository and several blog posts but when using `invoke --raw` they use simpler examples.

I'm extracting the event from a json file and this is what I came up with:

```
zappa invoke staging "import json;data = open('file/object.json');json_data = json.load(data);from lambda_function import lambda_handler;lambda_handler(json_data, {})" --raw
```

The response I get is:

```
[WARNING]   2019-08-22T22:31:19.866Z    4fd26bb6-b369-40a6-b5c2-b5a5f5e0bd21    Invalid request
```

Maybe I'm sending the event wrong, is there another way to send it?
Also, even if it is sending the event right I wanted to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: The code looks alright. I'll check that the lambda is able to import `lambda_handler` from `lambda_function` and that the `file/object.json` is available in the AWS lambda environment.
You can look in the Cloudwatch logs to trace what exact error is happening. 

Is the event file available the local machine that you're running the command in?
If  yes, there may another way to invoke the handler with the event.

Comment: Now I'm testing directly in AWS and get a more compete error log in CloudWatch, I think the issue has to do other with credentials not properly set in the environment, once that is I'l make an update. And yes, the event is available in the local machine.